# How do I read from and write to an object with an enum and associated custom objects?

Tags: swift, enums, swiftui

I'm trying to wrap my head around how to make a codable object for Firestore that can hold an array of custom object types within it. I've managed to create a codable object with an enum for each object type I want to store, but I'm struggling with how to read from it or write to it, and I'm starting to suspect I'm on the wrong path entirely.

Below is an example of what I'm trying to do.

```
struct myView:View {
    @Binding var entry:JournalEntry
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Title: \(entry.title)")
            Text("Content: \(/* WHAT TO PUT HERE? */)")
            TextField("RecordA text", text: /* WHAT TO PUT HERE? */)
        }
    }
}

struct Journal:Codable, Identifiable {
   var id = UUID().uuidString
   var entries:[JournalEntry]
}

struct JournalEntry:Codable, Identifiable {
    var id:String
    var title: String
    var date:Date
    var entryContent:EntryType
}

struct RecordA: Codable {
    var text:String = ""
    var image:String = ""
}

struct RecordB: Codable {
    var laps:Int = 0
    var jumps:Int = 0
}

enum EntryType: Codable {
    case recordTypeA(RecordA)
    case recordTypeB(RecordB)
}

extension EntryType {

private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case base, recordTypeAObject, recordTypeBObject
}

private enum Base: String, Codable {
    case recordTypeA, recordTypeB
}

func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    switch self {
    case .recordTypeA:
        try container.encode(RecordA(), forKey: .recordTypeAObject)
    case .recordTypeB:
        try container.encode(RecordB(), forKey: .recordTypeBObject)
    }
}

init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    let base = try container.decode(Base.self, forKey: .base)
    switch base {
    case .recordTypeA:
        if let content = try? decoder.singleValueContainer().decode(RecordA.self) {
            self = .recordTypeA(content)
            return
        }
    case .recordTypeB:
        if let content = try? decoder.singleValueContainer().decode(RecordB.self) {
            self = . recordTypeB(content)
            return
        }
    }
    
    throw ContentError.missingValue
}

enum ContentError:Error {
    case missingValue
}
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For viewing the content I would create a view for each struct

```
struct RecordAView: View {
    var record: RecordA
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(record.image)
            Text(record.text)
        }
    }
}

struct RecordBView: View {
    var record: RecordB
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("\(record.jumps)")
            Text("\(record.laps)")
        }
    }
}
```

and then modify the `myView` for displaying the correct data

```
struct myView:View {
    @Binding var entry:JournalEntry

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Title: \(entry.title)")
            viewForContent(entry.entryContent)
        }
    }

    func viewForContent(_ content: EntryType) -> some View {
        switch content {
            case .recordTypeA(let record):
                return AnyView(RecordAView(record: record))
            case .recordTypeB(let record):
                return AnyView(RecordBView(record: record))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That definitely solves the read issue. Maybe I could make the record a @state and create a function in the view for writing the data directly to Firestore? Not a pretty solution, but it's the only thing I can think of right now.